# Login form using post only works once? cant find the error

Tags: java, android, android-activity, httprequest

I have had this problem and i cant figure out how to sort this out. I am using android studio to compile my project. The problem im having is that i can only send the Login information once with success which is weird for me. I am not an advanced android programmer.

Here is the code that im having the problem with:

```
public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);
    try {
        List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass.getText().toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    String responsestr = null;
    JSONObject json = null;
    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        entity = response.getEntity();
        try {
            responsestr = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "We have good response string", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(responsestr);
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Integer success = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            json = null;
            try {
                json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                success = json.getInt("success");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "We Have a good return", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (success == 1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }
}
```

Now as i said it works once then it becomes non responsive if you retry loging in or correcting the username password?

Really not sure how to fix this. If i have left out any information let me know and i will be happy to provide it to you.

**Edit 1(Could be a long night):**

Ok i have seen that the post works each time before the application goes non responsive. it seems as if it only retrieves the data once and then never again even if the application is closed and reopened. it will only work again if i recompile from Android studio then it goes back to its non responsive sate :(.

**Edit 2:**

Sorry Guys here is how i call the async task from an onClick event attached to the login button

```
public void sendMessage(View view){

    String s1, s2;

    s1 = user.getText().toString();
    s2 = pass.getText().toString();


    if ((s1.matches("")) || (s2.matches(""))) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.studentpa.Dashboard.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: In what part of the code, is it becoming unresponsive? It seems to me that this could be an issue somewhere else. How do you call the `AsyncTask` from your code?

Comment: @Darwind Hey bud. added the onClick event where i call the async task, Take a look. Where do you think the error could be and what other info should i provide?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is any of your code, that could make your app un-responsive. Try to run through the code, with the debugger active. See where it stops... are you sure, your server code, is not creating some unwanted state? Perhaps returning some bogus JSON?

Comment: @Darwind Hey bud. Sorted out the problem, first of all like you said the server was not returning correctly encoded JSON, Secondly the post data was taking up too much processing power on the main thread so i included it in the AsyncTask and thirdly i had unhandled exceptions, i have posted the answer of how i sorted it out. Thanks for the help bud.

Comment: Good to know and great that you posted the answer, although it might be a little hard for other people to use, since it was a server-issue :-)

Comment: @Darwind very true bud, although the server issue was just an incorrect JSON encoding problem, I will do an edit with the PHP Code for people to see. Cheers bud and thanks for the help

Comment: @Darwind hey bud, added the server code for users to see the full soluction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution to my problem, Please see the comments for the changes made, also here is the code that now works.

```
public void loginMethod(View view) {
    em = email.getText().toString();
    ps = pass.getText().toString();

    if (isConnected()) {
        if (em.contains(" ") || ps.contains(" ")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No spaces are allowed in either field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (em.matches("") || ps.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(em);

            email.setEnabled(false);
            pass.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not connected to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
        if (strResponse.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We have no response from the server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(strResponse);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONObject json;
            json = null;
            Integer success = 0;

            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                json = null;
                try {
                    json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    success = json.getInt("success");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (success == 1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (success == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Login Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        email.setEnabled(true);
        pass.setEnabled(true);

        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    public void postData(String s1) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.gbes.co.za");
        HttpEntity entity;

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", em));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", ps));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HttpHostConnectException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Edit:

**Hey Guys Here is the server code:**
The database connection is hidden for server protection

```
<?php
$uName=$_POST['username'];
$pWord=$_POST['password'];

$squl = "SELECT * FROM `usr` WHERE `uE`='".$uName."' && `uP`='".$pWord."' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($squl);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $logincount=$rows['uLC'];
        $logincount=$logincount + 1;
        $uid=$rows['ID'];
    }
    $nowtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $loginsql = "UPDATE `users` SET `uLC`=$logincount, `uLL`='$nowtime'";
    $query = mysql_query($loginsql);


    $login_ok = true;
} else {
    $login_ok = false;
}

if ($login_ok) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Login successful!"; 
    die("[".json_encode($response)."]");
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
    die("[".json_encode($response)."]");
}   
mysql_close($db);

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
?>
```